# How to maintain a release branch in git?

Tags: git, github, merge, gitlab, version-control

we have `master` branch and a `release` branch. We cant push directly to any of these two branches. We only merge into them from feature branches.

The idea is that `master` branch is the development branch where we push all the features first, `master` branch gets tested and then the `master` branch gets merged into the `release` branch.

What I do is

```
1. git checkout master
2. git pull origin master
3. git checkout -b feature-branch
   - do your code changes
4. git add <all the changes>
5. git commit -m "Change done"
6. git push origin feature-branch
```

Then I merge the feature-branch into the `master` branch. rinse and repeat.

once I complete a feature, I raise a merge request where I merge from `master` branch into my `release` branch.

at this point I am assuming that the `release` branch must be at par with the `master` branch.
But that is not the case.

Everytime I add a new `feature` branch in `master` and then when I try to merge `master` into `release` I see older commits (which should already be in `release` branch) still coming in the MR thats getting created.

on top of it the Graph looks as if the `release` and `master` branch are not in sync.

[image]

I tries rebasing changes into release branch's branch like this

```
1. git checkout release
2. git pull origin release --rebase
3. git checkout -b merge-master-to-release
4. git pull origin master --rebase
   - resolve conflicts if any
6. git push origin merge-master-to-release
```

Then merge `merge-master-to-release` into `release` branch so that `release` branch has all the latest `master` branch changes, but that too does not work well.

How to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Pick only necessary and tested/verified changes from **master** branch to **release** branch with *git cherry-pick* command:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Example usage:

1. Copy the sha code of the commit in **master** branch.
2. Checkout **release** branch.
3. Use command: git cherry-pick <sha>

Alternatively, *cherry-pick* action is supported directly in GitLab and GitHub also.